# NGINX Upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, Using POST request to upload file

Tags: express, nginx, file-upload, routes

I just recently deployed an app to AWS following this tutorial: https://dev.to/rmiyazaki6499/deploying-a-production-ready-react-express-app-on-aws-62m#project-layout, and for the most part everything seemed fine however on my POST request to my express server nothing seems to happen as nothing is being sent or returned. Everything works locally as I am able to upload a file and push it to an API. If there are any suggestions on how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const docparser = require('docparser-node');
const client = new docparser.Client("APIKEY");
const parserID = "cslfmvewjrvo";
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
//this creates the filestream needed to upload to API endpoint
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'client/public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage });

const fs = require('fs')




// Upload Route
app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/../client/public/uploads/${file.filename}`);

  
  if (file == null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }
  try 
  {
    let result = await client.uploadFileByStream(parserID, stream);
    let docID = result.id;
    console.log("This is the document ID: " + docID);
    console.log("waiting for response...");

    //We have to wait for a response from the API so thats what delay is for
    await delay(20000);
    let parsedData = await client.getResultsByDocument(parserID,docID, {format: 'object'});
    let transcript = parsedData[0].final;  

    return res.status(200).send(transcript); 
  } 
  catch (err) 
  {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'An error occurred' })
  }
});

// This function delays the actions of whatever code precedes it
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
};

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server Started...'));
```

FileUpload.js

```js
//FileUpload.js

import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect,useMemo } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Table from "./Table";
import Message from './Message';
import Progress from './Progress';
import '../App.css';
//This is the fileUploader Component. 
 
const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file,setFile] = useState('');
  const [fileName,setFileName] = useState('Choose File');
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);
  const [tableData,setTableData] = useState(true);
 


const onChange = e => {
  setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
  };


  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
          setUploadPercentage(
            parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            )
          );
        }
      });
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(setData);
      setTableData(false);
      
      // Clear percentage
      setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 10000);

      const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

      setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });

      setMessage('Transcript Uploaded');
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        setMessage('There was a problem with the server');
      } else {
        setMessage(err.response.data.msg);
      }
      setUploadPercentage(0)
    }
  };

  /* 
    - Columns is a simple array right now, but it will contain some logic later on. It is recommended by react-table to memoize the columns data
    - Here in this example, we have grouped our columns into two headers. react-table is flexible enough to create grouped table headers
  */
    const columns = useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          // first group - Schedule
          Header: "Schedule",
          // First group columns
          columns: [
            {
              Header: "Course",
              accessor: "course"
            },
            {
              Header: "Coursename",
              accessor: "coursename"
            },
            {
              Header: "Attempted",
              accessor: "attempted"
            },
            {
              Header: "Received",
              accessor: "received"
            }
            ,
            {
              Header: "Grade",
              accessor: "grade"
            }

          ]
        }
      ],
      []
    );





  return (
    <Fragment>
      {message ? <Message msg={message} /> : null}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className='custom-file mb-4'>
          <input
            type='file'
            className='custom-file-input'
            id='customFile'
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>
            {fileName}
          </label>
        </div>

        <Progress percentage={uploadPercentage} />

        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Upload'
          className='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4'
        />
      </form>
      {uploadedFile ? (
        <div className='row mt-5'>
          <div className='col-md-6 m-auto'>
            <h3 className='text-center'>{uploadedFile.fileName}</h3>
            <img style={{ width: '100%' }} src={uploadedFile.filePath} alt='' />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {tableData ? (
         <p/>
         ):
         ( 
         <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
         )
      }
      
    </Fragment>
  );
};
 
export default FileUpload
```

Nginx config

```
server {
server_name 52.200.122.98;

# react app & front-end files
location / {
root /home/ubuntu/KUAutoadvisor/client/build/;
try_files $uri /index.html;
}

# node api reverse proxy // the /api/ is assuming your api routes start with that i.e. www.your-site.com/api/endpoint
location /api/ {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 4096m;
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: So it seems like it was an issue with starting pm2 with --watch as when I restarted the process without it, it seemed to work as intended. From what I read there is an issue with multer and --watch in which the express server never receives the intended data.